# What song plays during the episode preview after ending in Tokyo Ghoul:re episode 6?

Tags: music, tokyo-ghoul

There's a music in *Tokyo Ghoul:re* episode 6 at the end, after the ending music (the next episode preview).

What is that song?

Comment: You mean the piano?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure its Phase Shift by Yukata Yamada, at the beginning or at 3:30. here's a link, hopefully I'm right
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hWqWMh2PKP8